# Extract variable names using stringr in R

Tags: r, regex, split, stringr, stringi

I am trying to extract some variable names and numbers from the following vector and store them into two new variables:

```
unique_strings <- c("PM_1_PMS5003_S_Avg", "PM_2_5_PMS5003_S_Avg", "PM_10_PMS5003_S_Avg", 
  "PM_1_PMS5003_A_Avg", "PM_2_5_PMS5003_A_Avg", "PM_10_PMS5003_A_Avg", 
  "PNC_0_3_PMS5003_Avg", "PNC_0_5_PMS5003_Avg", "PNC_1_0_PMS5003_Avg", 
  "PNC_2_5_PMS5003_Avg", "PNC_5_0_PMS5003_Avg", "PNC_10_0_PMS5003_Avg", 
  "PM_1_PMS7003_S_Avg", "PM_2_5_PMS7003_S_Avg", "PM_10_PMS7003_S_Avg", 
  "PM_1_PMS7003_A_Avg", "PM_2_5_PMS7003_A_Avg", "PM_10_PMS7003_A_Avg", 
  "PNC_0_3_PMS7003_Avg", "PNC_0_5_PMS7003_Avg", "PNC_1_0_PMS7003_Avg", 
  "PNC_2_5_PMS7003_Avg", "PNC_5_0_PMS7003_Avg", "PNC_10_0_PMS7003_Avg"
)
```

I would like to extract each character before the `PMS` for the first variable. This includes the strings that being with `PM` or `PNC`, as well as the underscores and digits. I would like to store these results into a variable called `pollutant`.

Desired output:

```
unique(pollutant)
[1] "PM_1" "PM_2_5" "PM_10" "PNC_0_3" "PNC_0_5" "PNC_1_0" "PNC_2_5" "PNC_5_0" "PNC_10"
```

I would like to extract everything after the `PMS` for the second variable.

For this, I first tried extracting just the model numbers (four-digit numbers ending in `003`) from each string, however, it would be useful to include the `A_Avg` or `S_Avg` in the extraction as well.

Here's my first attempt:

```
model_id <- str_extract(unique_strings, "[0-9]{4,}")

unique(model_id)
[1] "5003" "7003"
```

I have not used regex before and am having a difficult time navigating existing docs / stack posts. Your input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_split` to split the string based on `"PMS"`. After that, use `str_replace` to remove the last `"_"` in the first column. The output is `m`. The first variable is in the first column, while the second variable is in the second column.

```
library(stringr)
m <- str_split(unique_strings, pattern = "PMS", simplify = TRUE)
m[, 1] <- str_replace(m[, 1], "_$", "")
m
#       [,1]       [,2]        
#  [1,] "PM_1"     "5003_S_Avg"
#  [2,] "PM_2_5"   "5003_S_Avg"
#  [3,] "PM_10"    "5003_S_Avg"
#  [4,] "PM_1"     "5003_A_Avg"
#  [5,] "PM_2_5"   "5003_A_Avg"
#  [6,] "PM_10"    "5003_A_Avg"
#  [7,] "PNC_0_3"  "5003_Avg"  
#  [8,] "PNC_0_5"  "5003_Avg"  
#  [9,] "PNC_1_0"  "5003_Avg"  
# [10,] "PNC_2_5"  "5003_Avg"  
# [11,] "PNC_5_0"  "5003_Avg"  
# [12,] "PNC_10_0" "5003_Avg"  
# [13,] "PM_1"     "7003_S_Avg"
# [14,] "PM_2_5"   "7003_S_Avg"
# [15,] "PM_10"    "7003_S_Avg"
# [16,] "PM_1"     "7003_A_Avg"
# [17,] "PM_2_5"   "7003_A_Avg"
# [18,] "PM_10"    "7003_A_Avg"
# [19,] "PNC_0_3"  "7003_Avg"  
# [20,] "PNC_0_5"  "7003_Avg"  
# [21,] "PNC_1_0"  "7003_Avg"  
# [22,] "PNC_2_5"  "7003_Avg"  
# [23,] "PNC_5_0"  "7003_Avg"  
# [24,] "PNC_10_0" "7003_Avg"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This did the trick and I'm feeling more comfortable with regex now!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to match either 'PM' or 'PNC' from the start (`^`) of the string (`^(PM|PNC)`) followed by a `_` and one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by cases that have another set of `_` and digits (for this we specify zero or more (`(_\\d)*`)

```
library(stringr)
out <- str_extract(unique_strings, "^(PM|PNC)_\\d+(_\\d)*")
```

This will give `NA` for those elements that don't have a match.  If we need to remove those

```
na.omit(out)
```

---

For the second case, it is not clear about the desired output.  If we need to to extract everything after the `PMS`, we can do with a regexlookbehind to(`(?<=PMS)`) and match all the characters that follow (`.*`)

```
str_extract(unique_strings, "(?<=PMS).*")
```